# Unable to remove itemframes with items in it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

To be unable to remove item frames with items in it has been a problem in my world for a long amount of time; I have a world that is about 4-5 years old and updated to the newest version. I can remove item frames with no items in them, but when I put an item in it, I can't break it unless I break the block behind it or doing /kill.

I don't know if this is command block related or if it is a bug. If anyone knows why this is happening, please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you punch it, nothing happens? That's strange. What about shooting it with a bow, placing a block in it or opening a shulker box into it from the side?

Comment: If I place a block in it or open a shulker, it breaks. If I punch or shoot it, the break sound plays w/o it breaking

Comment: And you're sure this only happens with filled item frames? Are you maybe on a server with spawn protection enabled? (But even then it shouldn't behave like that.)

Comment: This is a single-player world; vanilla. It only happens with filled item frames, here I'll send you a video. https://imgur.com/a/qpdqdwA

Comment: It's weird. When I shoot an arrow at it, the arrow just disappears.

Comment: Do you have any commands running, like datapacks or command blocks? They could set the item frame to invulnerable. Try these commands: `/gamerule commandBlockOutput true`, `/gamerule logAdminCommands true`, `/gamerule sendCommandFeedback true`

Comment: nope, nothing except a clock adding 1 to my score on a scoreboard.

Comment: Have you tried it in a new world already? Does it work properly there?

Comment: Yes I did try another world and it worked as it should

Comment: At this point maybe a world download would be helpful.

Comment: The world save is 255 MB but I can link the world anyways. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x5uhydj93jzg3b0/WorldSave.zip?dl=0

Sorry for not responding, I was not at my computer.

Comment: I ran `/gamerule commandBlockOutput true` and was immediately spammed with output. You do have commands running! Why do you answer what happens when you run a command if you didn't even run that command?

Comment: There are also datapacks active… -.-

Comment: The world was on a modded server before. Removing mods is like downgrading, all kinds of crazy things could go wrong with that.

Comment: And Fabric apparently as well…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your world was apparently used on a Forge server and also with Fabric in the past. Removing mods is similarly bad as downgrading, all kinds of things can go wrong that way. Even if a Vanilla bug causes this item frame behaviour, it would not be valid on the bug tracker.

Tracking down exactly what is wrong in that world is very difficult (I tried the usual things, they didn't help), so I would recommend using the "recreate world" button in the world selection screen on your world, exiting the newly created world again and copying the folders `region` (Overworld), `DIM-1` (Nether), `DIM1` (End) and `datapacks` over to the new world. That should keep the most important things, while avoiding the item frame issue to creep in. You will have to recreate scoreboards and some other things, but the main parts of the world are saved.

If you want to put in more effort and actually find the exact cause, you can take one folder at a time from your old world and overwrite the folder in the new world with it. Once the problem occurs again, make a new world, copy everything that you know works and proceed by copying over the sub-folders of the problematic folder or the files in it. Once you found the file that causes the issue, you can compare it with a working one in NBTExplorer.

Comment: If I use the method where I copy the region, DIM1, and DIM-1 as well as data packs. Do entities get removed?

also, why it has forge and fabric is because I use world edit.

Comment: Found it, it was in the level.dat file

Comment: No, entities are saved in the chunks, so copying the 3 dimensions also copies over all entities, as well as light, structure boundaries (like witch huts) and much more. Also, what have you found, what is with level.dat?

Comment: I don't know, I opened it in NBTExplorer and deleted some tags: IsModded:1, etc, but I still can't break item frames in the original world. Here is the nbt
https://imgur.com/a/g75dOvk

Comment: So if you copy everything except level.dat, you can break item frames? I didn't test that. You could then try setting various tags to their default using https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Java_Edition_level_format#level.dat_format .

Comment: Should I delete every tag that isn't on the list?

Comment: You could try that, yes.